# I wanna know that how to auto resizing of textview in constraint layout

Tags: android

I would like to know how to automatically adjust the size of the text view in proportion to the device screen size, not the contents of the official Android reference document.

Comment: What's wrong with the official documentation? Which part does it not cover/which part are you confused about?

Comment: The official document states that the size of the text view is adjusted at regular intervals according to the size of the screen, but I want to adjust the size of the text view as an accurate number to match the size of the device that actually runs the app.